# WARN [org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler] Exception while processing batch

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception, dwr

In my DWR application I caught this trace, but strange thing is nothing broke up from application perspective and it logged only once for same set of steps.

Does anyone knows/encounter similar?

```
WARN  [org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler] Exception while processing batch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find parameter: batchId (check server log for more info).
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.extractParameter(Batch.java:143)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.parseParameters(Batch.java:80)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:60)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.CallBatch.<init>(CallBatch.java:46)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:76)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:126)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:144)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doGet(DwrServlet.java:131)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:300)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:374)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:743)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:675)
        at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:866)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Internet Explorer?

I got the same error some weeks ago. 
After doing some investigation/debugging found the reason.

Internet Explorer has a limit for GET petitions urls size of 2,083 characters (  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427) if you exceed that limit it automatically cuts the url to match that size(without saying anything).

If you check DWR code (engine.js) you will find that it finally uses `<script>` tag for petitions when there is a crossDomain call. That is basically a GET call. In my case the url generated was larger than the limit of Internet Explorer, so it was automatically cut down to the correct size.
DWR use that batchID for identify petitions and usually puts in on the end of the URL so when IE cuts the url,  usually the batchId goes away with that "correction", making dwr to throw that exception since is unable to find it on the URL.

To solve this, i was forced to use JSONP (http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/remoting_options.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had hard time with this too, but finally i got figured it out. It seems some html elements id or javascript variable defined within the page where you are using dwr is colliding with engine.js's code

example: put this code inside body tag of the page where dwr is used

```
<div id="attributes" style="position: relative;">

    </div>
```

Now you can see that error coming. Only if you can change the id *attributes* to something else the error will be gone.